# patching a collection to add a field

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm wanting to patch a RavenDB to add a field to a collection but am just getting errors using the suggested syntax. (I'm probably not understanding what I'm supposed to use)

I've tried the following in the patch window but get error: ' "Message": "Deserializing Json object with empty string as property name is not supported."
'

```
store
    .DatabaseCommands
    .Patch(
        new ScriptedPatchRequest
        {
            Script = "_.extend(this, { 'GroupPlayString': 'Group Play'});"
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
        Script = "this.GroupPlayString = 'Group Play'"
```

Comment: thanks and so easy. Would be nice if the ravendb documentation had included a simple example like this. For clarification to anyone who also uses this answer you don't use the 'script =' part, it's just: this.GroupPlayString = 'Group Play'